# webview code not working

Tags: ios, ios5, uiwebview

```
-(bool) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        BrowserLinker *linker= [[BrowserLinker alloc]initWithNibName:@"BLinker" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:linker  animated:YES];
        return NO;
    }
    else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

I have a UIWebView declared in the BrowserLinker class, and that method also declared. When a link is clicked in UIWebView, it has to open in a new ViewController. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with code? Btw code is adapted from SO answer.

> **ERROR**: WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:request:newFrameName:decisionListener: delegate:  Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'BLinker'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nib filenames generally share the same basename as their accompanying view controller filenames.  Here you've got the view controller called `BrowserLinker` and the nib called `BLinker`.  Are you sure your nib isn't called `BrowserLinker`?

Comment: Are you sure you've added it to the target you are building?